# AS 2 - Pulling info from multiple arrays in a loop for buttons

Tags: arrays, for-loop, actionscript-2

I have 3 arrays.

**- Array 1** Button names

**- Array 2** x positions

**- Array 3** y positions

I have all of the movieclips on the stage w/button names and a movieclip named test. I'm trying to make each mc button move the "test" movieclip to a specific location.

I'm able to loop through the buttons but unable to get the current number of the button in the array to use for the x and y coordinates.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
            var hrN:Array = new Array(bHRSD,bMASP,bGLD,bGRBDS,bWIe,bGC,bGHCM,bMCRGB,bCE);
            var hrNX:Array = new Array(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90);
            var hrNY:Array = new Array (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90);



            for(var i=0; i<hrN.length; i++) {
                hrN[i].button = i;
                hrN[i].onRelease = function()   {
                    test._x = hrNX[trying to get the current number of the hrN array here];
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're unbelievably close :

```
var hrN:Array = new Array(bHRSD,bMASP,bGLD,bGRBDS,bWIe,bGC,bGHCM,bMCRGB,bCE);
var hrNX:Array = new Array(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90);
var hrNY:Array = new Array (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90);



for(var i=0; i<hrN.length; i++) {
    hrN[i].button = i;//you're storing the index here as the button property
    hrN[i].onRelease = function()   {
        //so use it here
        test._x = hrNX[this.button];
    }
}
```